# HTML5 link to another page element navigates to top of page instead of specified element

Tags: css, html

have anyone encountered following problem? 
First of all my directory looks like that:

```
/root
    index.html
    /blog
        /category
        posts.html
            /post
            mypostname.html
```

I use Bootstrap 4.
 
I want to navigate from my index.html to div element on **/blog/category/post/mypostname.html**

---

My index.html code looks like this:

```
<a href="blog/category/post/mypostname.html#post-body-mg-1">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-warning">Czytaj więcej &hellip;</button>
</a>
```

---

Code on destination page:

```
<div id="post-body-mg-1">(it has content)</div>
```

---

The problem is, it navigates to the top of the blogs page instead specified div element. When I put similiar link inside posts.html page, clicked it navigates to that element without problem.

---

When I write this link like that (notice slash / after posts.html):

```
<a href="blog/category/post/mypostname.html/#post-body-mg-1">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-warning">Czytaj więcej &hellip;</button>
</a>
```

It sure works and navigates to specified div but! it fails to load stylesheets because it makes that mypostname.html file one step deeper into directory.
What's even funnier when I add additional level of path (../) in links to stylesheets to match this deepened directory it loads everything fine but again stops navigating to specified element!
Could it be an issue with bootstrap4? I doubt it cuz it doesnt involve bootstrap mechanics, does it?

---

Please feedback my answer structure as well if its incorrect because I'm new on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a href="blog/dsp2017/post/mypostname.html#post-body-mg-1">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-warning">Czytaj więcej &hellip;</button>
</a>

<a href="blog/category/post/mypostname.html/#post-body-mg-1">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-warning">Czytaj więcej &hellip;</button>
</a>
```

Two links are different having

> dsp2017

have something to do with that?

Comment: Oh, as I was copying this from my actual project it seems I've forgotten to change name to generic one. 
Unfortunately it has nothing to do with that. 
Im gonna edit it right now to avoid further confusions.